# titanium appcelerator .javascript: Invalid number

Tags: ios, titanium, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

[INFO] :   Creating assets image set
[INFO] :   Processing JavaScript files

[ERROR] :  /Users/delegate/Documents/Axyway_Appc_Workspace/reservationplusmaintenance/MobileApplication/Resources/ui/common/reservation/searchResultsByScheduleWindow[image: .js: Invalid number] (996:19)

Getting the above error when building the app for the ios device.But, works fine in ios simulator.

Have any idea why this happens? Im using Titanium SDK 7.0.0 GA and building for ios 11

Comment: simulator is not case sensitive, device is. Perhaps wrong casing?

Comment: Also, moment is embedded, you can get it by doing `require('alloy/moment')`